# Display a QMessageBox from a QThread

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I want to display a message box from a separate thread, however, I get this error:

`QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`

Can anyone explain how to display a message box from a thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emit a signal.  Since you cannot do UI stuff in a `Qthread`, instead send your message as an argument of your signal.

signal decalaration in your qthread:

```
signals:
  void write2SysStatus(QString theMessage);
```

emitting the signal from the qthread:

```
emit write2SysStatus("Some status");
```

slot declaration/definition in QMainWindow:

```
public slots:
  void eWriteLine ( QString theMessage ){
       //this is where you use you message box.
  }
```

connecting of the slot and signal:

```
connect(pFPSengine, SIGNAL(write2SysStatus(QString)), this,SLOT(eWriteLine(QString)));
```