# Display a QMessageBox from C code running in a QThread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, qt

I have the main (GUI) thread which creates a QThread.

In the QThread, I am calling a C function that needs to display a QMessageBox. So far, I simply used:

```
void notify(char *str)
{
  QMessageBox::information(0, "", QString(str));
}
```

in the C++ code and called it from the C code. This worked fine without threads, but now with threads I am getting errors, because one cannot call the GUI functions from another thread.

Usually, this could be circumvented by using signals like the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299493/display-a-qmessagebox-from-a-qthread) suggests; however, I doubt I can do this from the C code.

So, how can I make the C code communicate with the GUI thread and tell it to display a QMessageBox?

Thanks.

P.S.

If possible, I'd like to do this without touching the C code (as of now, there is simply an `extern void notify(char *)` declaration in the C code's headers, and if possible I'd like it to stay at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a `QWidget` or `QMainWindow` derived class for your GUI, you could add the following to it:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT;
public:    
    MyWidget()
    {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(notify_sig(QString)),
                this, SLOT(notify_slot(QString)),
                Qt::QueuedConnection);
    }

    void notify(QString str)
    {
        emit notify_sig(str);
    }

    signals:
        void notify_sig(QString str);

    slots:
        void notify_slot(QString str)
        {
            QMessageBox::information(0, "", str);
        }
};
```

Here you have a public function `notify()` that is a member of the widget class.  Calling `MyWidget::notify()` results in a signal being sent to itself through a queued connection (which will result in the slot being called in the GUI thread).  Now the C `notify()` call just needs to call the widget/window's `notify()` function.  This can be tricky since you don't really have a pointer to the widget available in the C `notify()` function.

Normally, the C interface would allow the user to pass a `void*` value in and would then return that value with the notify call.  This would allow you to pass in the pointer to `MyWidget` when the C function is called and then cast it back to `MyWidget` in the `notify()` implementation.

```
MyWidget* wid = ...;
C_function(arg1, ..., wid);

//...

void notify(char* str, void* userdata)
{
    MyWidget* wid = static_cast<MyWidget*>(userdata);
    wid->notify(QString(str));
}
```

If you can't change the C interface, you may need to use some kind of global way of getting the widget/window's pointer.

Note that I have not tested any of this code and there may be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I think you misread my answer a little or I explained it wrong, but the `notify` (non-class) function is actually in the C++ code (the C code only calls it) which makes it a little easier since I **can** get the pointer to the `MyWidget` in your example. So, I can call my main window class' methods which then use signals & slots as you suggested. But anyway, I used your approach, it works fine (except the compiler didn't like `public signals`, it's just `signals`), so thanks a lot!