# Getting QInputDialog::getText() result from C code running in non-GUI thread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, qt

I have previously solved a similar problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589299/display-a-qmessagebox-from-c-code-running-in-a-qthread), where I asked how to display a QMessageBox from a non-GUI thread in Qt running C code.

The solution I was suggested, to use signals & slots and a Qt::QueuedConnection to connect a signal that could be emitted by the C code calling a C++ function that in turn called a C++ method of my main GUI window which then emitted the signal, works fine for QMessageBoxes.

However, now I also need to be able to request input from the user from a QInputDialog, from the C code running in the non-GUI thread.

I have thought about using the following slot code and the same principle described above:

```
void MyWidget::prompt_slot(QString str, QString &answer)
{
  answer = QInputDialog::getText(0, "", str);
}
```

and a Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection, so that the slot modifies the reference to a string that I can then access from the C code.

Unfortunately I get the following runtime error:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QString&'
(Make sure 'QString&' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

What am I doing wrong? Will by approach even work? If not, what should I use?

Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ought to work if you use `QString*` instead of `QString&`.  You may have to also register `QString*` as a metatype - or, if you can't be bothered doing that, use `void*` instead and cast back and forth.

Comment: Well, that was easy, using a pointer instead of a reference works. Thanks!